# Translate form helper to simple_form or formstatic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have this in my model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES = [
    "single",
    "in a relationship",
    "together",
    "it's complicated"
  ]

  validates :relationship_status, :inclusion => RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES
end
```

This in the view:

```
collection_select(:person, :relationship_status, Person::RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES, :to_s)
```

And I would like to translate that to simple_form. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, it's simple(it's for `formtastic`):

```
<%= form.input :relationship_status, :as => :select, :collection => Person::RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES %>
```

Comment: You don't need the :as options if you want to use the select collection